# Android : Your device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android

[image]

Currently my app is uploaded on play store and Android kitkat (4.4) devices is not compatible to install my app, my app min target API is 16, I attached image also

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<permission
    android:name="com.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<application
    android:name="Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".help.HelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".help.Disclaimer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

What should i do for this?

Comment: I think you should remove the uses-feature tags, and try again

Comment: ok let me try to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing this

```
<uses-feature
   android:name="android.hardware.camera"
   android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But after doing this you have to take care about the features, if not available.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `<uses-feature>`.

`<uses-feature>` - Declares a single hardware or software feature that is used by the application.

The purpose of a  declaration is to inform any external entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your application depends. The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it. Because feature support can vary across Android devices, the  element serves an important role in letting an application describe the device-variable features that it uses.
[*read for more*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: I had a similar problem because of the autofocus feature.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove `uses-feature` or add `required=false` in it. Only this will help. I had similar problem with my app and this worked. But, doing this means handling the features, if not available.